# compare in array with specific condition value

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting array after loping

```
while($num_rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($data_query_details1))
```

Now I want to check if my specific user_id ( suppose here user_id=3) stay  2/3 ( my specific value) times  same date in array then `print ok` otherwise `print need more`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [user_id] => 3
    [1] => 2014-07-18
    [date(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))] => 2014-07-18
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [user_id] => 3
    [1] => 2014-07-18
    [date(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))] => 2014-07-18
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [user_id] => 4
    [1] => 2014-07-18
    [date(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))] => 2014-07-18
)
```

any logic ?

Comment: You can have the database give you the answer directly by using the appropriate query. Is there a reason not to do that?

Comment: I have not enough query knowledge so trying to do this way @Jon

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array();
$stay = false;
$userid_to_check = 3;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data_query_details1)){
    if($row['user_id']==$userid_to_check){
        if(in_array($row[1], $dates)){
            $stay = true;
            break;
        }
        $dates[] = $row[1];
    }
}
if($stay)echo 'ok';
else echo 'need more';
```

It's better to go with a more direct database select like the answers above though.
For example, what codebird mentioned:

```
$query = "select count(*) from your_table GROUP BY user_id HAVING date(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))='2014-07-18'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count>=2)echo 'ok';
else echo 'need more';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM your_table 
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))='2014-07-18' 
GROUP BY user_id
```